partial differential equations methods
I am doing an assignment for my General relativity course where I am asked to find a coordinate transformation between $$ (X, T) \rightarrow (\hat{x}, \hat{t}) $$ coordinate systems.
Such that the line elements
$$ 
ds^2=-X^2dT^2 + dX^2 = e^\frac{2x}{L} (d\hat{x}^2-d\hat{t}^2)
=d\hat{s}^2 $$
By applying this property I manged to find this differential equation
$$
\
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\hat{x}} \log X - \frac{\partial T}{\partial \hat{x}}\right) = \frac{\partial T}{\partial \hat{t}} - \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\hat{t}} \log X\right)
\
$$
Now I am kinda stuck, mostly because I never solved PDE's in my math courses.
Could you please give me a reference where to look to solve such equations?
I tried to write something like this
$$
\
\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial \hat{x}}\right)  = - \frac{\partial u}{\partial \hat{t}} 
\
$$
This reminds me of the condition of closure of 1-forms.
With u :
$$ u = logX-T$$
and the apply some sort of assumptions like separtion of variables.
$$ u=H(\hat{x})G(\hat{t})$$

Since you need to find just one such a transformation (not all of them), try $\hat t=T$ and see what it gives. [For transforming more general 2-dim metrics it is a good idea to compute the isotropic (=lightlike) curves, but here you likely don't need it.]

I thought to do it, but maybe it is not a formal way to get the result? I will try thanks

What if to solve the PDE I use Fourier Transfromation would that be a good idea?
